# NGINX proxy_pass to url not working

Tags: nginx

I am new to NGINX, so I'm assuming it's something with my config.  I'm trying to take services2.sample.com and direct it to the url "http://10.10.128.65:86/dealer/#/login/QS36F"

`server {
 listen 80;
   server_name services2.sample.com;
   location / {
      proxy_redirect off;
      proxy_set_header   Host             $host;
      proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      client_max_body_size       10m;
      client_body_buffer_size    128k;
      proxy_connect_timeout      90;
      proxy_send_timeout         90;
      proxy_read_timeout         90;
      proxy_buffer_size          4k;
      proxy_buffers              4 32k;
      proxy_busy_buffers_size    64k;
      proxy_temp_file_write_size 64k;
      proxy_pass http://10.10.128.65:86/dealer/#/login/QS36F;
  }
}`

Comment: The URL fragment is only handled client side. It is meaningless and ignored at the server side. You probably need to rethink some aspect of your application's design.

Comment: Even if I just do a proxy_pass http://1010.128.65:86; I get a 502 Bad Gateway error.  If I don't try to change the port I get the default page for remote server.  I need to hit port 86 on the remote server to serve up the right page.

Comment: Do you have an error message? or log snippet? The config seems ok, but maybe nginx is interpreting that # as a comment, try replace it for %23.